# OpenTok WebRTC Styling Issue

Tags: ios, cordova, webrtc, opentok

We're building an iOS (iPad) app w/ PhoneGap & the OpenTok phonegap plugin. However, we're having an issue with styling. The actual video content does not span the entire width of the object element created via the opentok framework. We are passing explicit sizing parameters to opentok regarding the video, but we're still having this issue.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I cant reproduce your error, on my iOS device with the PhoneGap plugin, everything works the way it should be.

Here is my javascript code (in coffeescript):

```
session = ""
publisher = ""

subscribeToStreams = (streams)->
  for e in streams
    if (e.connection.connectionId == session.connection.connectionId)
      return
    div = document.createElement('div')
    div.setAttribute('id', 'stream' + e.streamId)
    div.setAttribute('class', "streamElement")
    document.body.appendChild( div )
    session.subscribe(e, div.id, {width: 640, height:480})

window.OTGroupChat = (apiKey, sessionId, token) ->
  publisher = TB.initPublisher(apiKey, "myPublisherDiv", {width: 320, height: 240})

  session = TB.initSession(sessionId)
  session.addEventListener 'sessionConnected', (event) ->
    session.publish( publisher )
    subscribeToStreams( event.streams )

  session.addEventListener 'streamCreated', (event) ->
    subscribeToStreams( event.streams )

  session.connect( apiKey, token )
```

The result: the publisher view shows up as 320x240 as expected, and the subscribed streams shows up at 640x480 as specified.

I then changed the subscribed stream's height by typing directly into the console:

```
$("object:last").height(100);
TB.updateViews();
```

The subscriber stream obediently resized to its new height.

I then tested if actual video content is smaller than the width of the object element by setting the object element's background color to pink. No pink showed, so the actual OpenTok video is either greater than or equal to the dimensions of the object element. When I gave the object element a pink border of size 1, there is a 1px pink outline around the video, showing that the object element is most certainly the same size as the video.

If I misunderstood you and you were referring to the black bars on either sides of the video, Im afraid that it is OpenTok's way to preserve aspect ratio and users trying to stream a portrait view  from their iOS device will often encounter back bars around their video.

[image]